# How to know some file metadata are read-only?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I can store some EXIF properties into a jpg picture by the code below.

```
var propertyToSave = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>() { 
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Photo.LensManufacturer", "Canon") };

await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(propertyToSave);
```

But actually some properties of EXIF listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff516600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are read-only.

E.g. if trying to set a read-only property, `"System.Photo.PeopleNames"`, an exception would be thrown.

```
// System.Photo.PeopleNames is a read-only property
var propertyToSave = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>() { 
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Photo.PeopleNames","Foo") 
};
```

ps: The value, `"Foo"` may not be the correct value corresponding to the key, `"System.Photo.PeopleNames"`. I just show an example.

My question, is there any way to know whether some file metadata are read-only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states which properties are read-only here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872003(v=vs.85).aspx